# failed to add host/datanode in ambari 2.7.5

Tags: ambari

I'm using Apache Ambari 2.7.5 to setup and maintain a hadoop cluster. Already managed to add a namenode and a datanode to local host (of ambari-master) but failed to add another datanode, it fials with warning encountered and in  /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/output-466.txt the last lines are:

```
2023-05-14 08:20:01,741 - FS Type: HDFS
2023-05-14 08:20:01,741 - XmlConfig['core-site.xml'] {'group': 'hadoop', 'conf_dir': '/etc/hadoop/conf', 'xml_include_file': None, 'configuration_attributes': {u'final': {u'fs.defaultFS': u'true'}}, 'owner': 'hdfs', 'only_if': 'ls /etc/hadoop/conf', 'configurations': ...}
2023-05-14 08:20:01,755 - Generating config: /etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml
2023-05-14 08:20:01,755 - File['/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml'] {'owner': 'hdfs', 'content': InlineTemplate(...), 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': None, 'encoding': 'UTF-8'}
2023-05-14 08:20:01,769 - Directory['/usr/lib/ambari-logsearch-logfeeder/conf'] {'create_parents': True, 'mode': 0755, 'cd_access': 'a'}
2023-05-14 08:20:01,769 - No logsearch configuration exists at /var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/BGTP/1.0/services/HDFS/package/templates/input.config-hdfs.json.j2
2023-05-14 08:20:01,769 - Could not load 'version' from /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/structured-out-466.json
```

Since all necessary packages was already installed by ambari agent and all configs been generated, i tried to start the datanode manually using "hdfs --daemon start datanode" after creatig hdfs dir in /home and chown the hdfs directory and it successfuly started and registerd to namenode.

How could i find out why ambari does not finish the task of adding the datanode? How could i find out the steps that ambari is executing to install datanode and in which step its stucking?